# MySQL: Rollback longer timeframe?

Tags: mysql, database, rollback, snapshot

I wondered, if I can somehow create a snapshot and, lets say two weeks later, return to this snapshot?
It should be applied to the entire database.

The easiest way would be to backup the database and then after two weeks delete the database and then restore the backup.
But I am trying to have a snapshot every night, so this could generate some disk space after a while. 
But maybe you know a better solution for this problem.
I am thinking of something like a diff, that only saves what changed since the last snapshot.

Is there something like this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a incremental backup solution. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

And look at he section about incremental backups :)